# How to debug react-native in Android Studio

Tags: android, react-native

I am coding React-native in Android Studio for Windows and using the Emulator. I have no idea how to debug my code?

How can I console.log in the code and see the results?
How can I inspect elements?
How can I put a break point in the code?

Any suggestion on the tools/tutorial will be a great help.

Thanks Negin

Answer (score 1):

1. Mark near line no. from where you want debug
2. Debug the project which shows beside the run icon.
3. Perform your Ui task where perform your debug line(it will shows mark near line number when it calls)
4. You can move the line up and down from debug console.

Answer (score -1):

TLDR: watch the [video](https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=3947160371991197)   starting at 19:9.

1. install fbflipper from the [link](https://fbflipper.com/).
2. install openSSl from [here](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) or if you have chocolatey type `choco install openssl`
3. add Path veriable locating where you have installed openssl [medium article link](https://medium.com/swlh/installing-openssl-on-windows-10-and-updating-path-80992e26f6a1)
4. enable hermes ([link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes))
5. best of luck.

Flipper allows you to debug app easily

Answer (score -4):

Here is the official document for debugging:
[Doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html)

You can debug the code in Chrome

- Open http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui in Chrome
- Run `npm start` on terminal
- Enable `remote debugging` on emulator by clicking `Command` + `m`

Comment: Does not answer the question, which is asking how to debug using Android Studio. The document you've linked to just has one tiny paragraph at the end stating that debugging can be performed in Android Studio but does not explain how.